# Button doesn't work. What code should I use?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good day,

I am a noob so please forgive me for a dumb question but I need some help with my website. I have a Get Started button with a transparent background. When user click on the button background should disappear. What code should I insert?

Many thanks, 
Alex

Website url: http://longplay.space/

Website code:

```
</div>
<div id="artmaps-map-themap"><iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zA9OSQj3vWR8.kZugAXwQLfOs" width="100%"  style="height:100%;"></iframe>   </div>
<div id="welcome">
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Putting vinyl shops collection on the map.</h2>
    <p>Long Play holds over 1,000 vinyl shops around the world.</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="explore-map" class="primary">Get started</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the entire #welcome div to disappear, or just the background?

Comment: Hi Jacob. I'm talking about #welcome div

Comment: Does my answer achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already included jQuery, just do a simple jQuery [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function:

```
$(function(){
   $(".primary").click(function(){ //Click function
      $("#welcome").hide(); //Hides ID welcome.
      //you could fade it out like $("#welcome").fadeOut();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this if you want to hide your background

```
$("#explore-map").on("click", 
  function(){ 
      $("#welcome").hide();
  });
```

or this if you want to delete it

```
$("#explore-map").on("click", 
  function(){ 
      $("#welcome").remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the button to be an actual button.

`<button href="#" onclick="myFunction()" id="explore-map" class="primary">Get started</button>`

Then add some javascript like this:

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById('welcome').style.background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
}
</script>
```

Add the js after your last /div. This does not delete the div #welcome but just sets the background to %100 transparent. Which is what I assumed you wanted.

Comment: Thanks. I inserted actual button and script before head but what do you mean about js after last /div?

Comment: The javascript is the script. Most of the time I put my javascript after all of the html in the body. So for you it would be after your last div or right before your closing body tag.